# Mobile frameworks for desktop

Tags: mobile

Came across a great list of current mobile frameworks. With such a huge variety I find it difficult in making a decision as to which to use for a web application to be used on both desktop and mobile.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_phone_web_based_application_framework

Has anyone used any of these?
Can any be extended and-or repurposed for use on the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I would say phonegap is your best bet. As you can use javascript, CSS and HTML to build it, you can definitely reuse that for desktop.